# Using a Select Statement as alias

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with regards to my mssql codes. What I have here is I counted the number of lines and results has their own designated result. My problem is I have to make the alias a select statement so as to make that column day name instead of making it hardcoded.

Here's the code for counting with results..

```
SELECT count(*) MONDAY
,CASE
    WHEN count(*) > 4
        THEN 1
    WHEN count(*) < 5
        THEN 0
END AS HIT_RARE
FROM
Tbl where msg like '%GGXX%' and date = '08/26/2015'
```

and this is what I need to place in as an alias in replacement for Monday which is actually hardcoded.

```
SELECT case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 'Sunday' ELSE
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 2 THEN 'Monday' ELSE 
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 3 THEN 'Tuesday' ELSE    
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 4 THEN 'Wednesday' ELSE  
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 5 THEN 'Thursday' ELSE   
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 6 THEN 'Friday' ELSE 
       case when DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
       END
```

Hope anyone came across such problem such as this one.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Can't add pictures yet....but column 1 must be named as Monday if today is monday then column 2 is hit rate...im only concerned on how to make the column name dynamic.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store result in temp table and rename it using [sp_rename]:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be2f2/1)**

```
DECLARE @alias_name NVARCHAR(100) = DATENAME(dw, GETDATE());

SELECT 
    (...)
   ,[alias] = (...)
INTO #temp
FROM table_name;

EXEC [tempdb]..[sp_rename] '#temp.alias', @alias_name, 'COLUMN';

SELECT *
FROM #temp;
```

But still cannot imagine it's usage in real life, as **COLUMN is not variable!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @sql =
'SELECT 
    count(*) AS ' +  QUOTENAME(DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()))  + '
    ,CASE
        WHEN count(*) > 4 THEN 1
        WHEN count(*) < 5 THEN 0
    END AS HIT_RARE
FROM Tbl
WHERE 
    msg like @msg
    AND date = @date'

PRINT @sql

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@msg VARCHAR(100), @date DATE', '%GGXX%', '20150826';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use pivot, but still require some sort of hard code, see sample below:

```
PRINT 'try pivot';
WITH   t AS ( SELECT   SomeCriteria,
                    DATENAME(WEEKDAY, SomeDate) WkDayName
           FROM     YourTable
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    t PIVOT
( COUNT(SomeCriteria) FOR WkDayName IN ( [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday],[Friday], [Saturday], [Sunday] ) ) AS p;
```

if you want to get rid of the weekday names in the query, then you might have to use dynamic SQL